# how to make links working like real in history API?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to make vanilla JavaScript routing by using history API. I tried to use this method `history.pushState()` to change my URLs and it works and renaming my URLs as I want but it doesn't work when **I refresh my page**

this snippet example using firebase but I think it will not working properly without running it locally with **live server** to generate localhost URLs:

```js
// start config genrated by firebase app //
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAFN-KRpzvA4Aup1FBtq6BRfaVl_ErkxpE",
    authDomain: "zeeda-f3f19.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://zeeda-f3f19.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "zeeda-f3f19",
    storageBucket: "zeeda-f3f19.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "295957581266",
    appId: "1:295957581266:web:e52b40b525f249a3"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// end genrated by firebase app //

// referance vriable //
const db = firebase.firestore();

const auth = firebase.auth()


/* start app  */

const title = document.getElementById('title')
const content = document.getElementById('content')
const blo1 = document.getElementById('blo1')
const blo2 = document.getElementById('blo2')
const blo3 = document.getElementById('blo3')

let blogid = '1';

blo1.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  blog('1');
})
blo2.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  blog('2')
})
blo3.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  blog('3')
})


function  blog(blogid){
  db.collection('blog').doc(blogid).get().then(snap =>{
    const titleData = snap.data().title;
    const contentData = snap.data().content;
      title.innerHTML = titleData;
      content.innerHTML = contentData;
      history.pushState({name:"blog"},'',`blog${blogid}`)
  })
}

  db.collection('blog').doc(blogid).get().then(snap =>{
    const titleData = snap.data().title
    const contentData = snap.data().content
      title.innerHTML = titleData
      content.innerHTML = contentData
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        ul {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            list-style: none;
            display: flex;
        }

        li {
            margin: 10px;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <button id="blo1">blog1</button>
            <button id="blo2">blog2</button>
            <button id="blo3">blog3</button>
        </ul>
    </nav>


<h1 id="title"></h1>
<p id="content"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone help me what i missing ? I read this [article](https://moz.com/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate) and he provide worked example [demo](http://html5.gingerhost.com/) he used jquery but I'm not familiar with it .

Comment: In order to receive help, please provide a minimal, reproducible example.
More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @CptChix I added code hope this clear now

Answer (score 1):

When the link is clicked JavaScript is used to make two things happen:

- The document is mutated into a different state
- The new URL is pushed into the history

(JavaScript also prevents the normal behaviour of a link (loading a whole new page) from happening).

By pushing the URL into the history you are, in effect, making a declaration that the URL represents the document you mutated the page into.

So to make that reality, you need to make the server, for that URL, serve up an HTML document which will give you that state.

This means that you need to:

- Generate the document in its final state for each URL *from the server*
- Generate the document in its final state for each URL *from client-side JavaScript*

You could do this with handcrafted static pages or with increasing levels of programmatically generated static pages or server side programming.

Yes, **this tends to involve a fair bit of work**. While `pushState` itself is quick and simple, it isn't a great deal of use without a lot of work done around it.

You can relieve a lot of effort by using shared templates, or building pages around frameworks like Next.JS which do server-side rendering of client side code.

Some people favour serving the same skeleton HTML document for *every* URL and loading all the content with JavaScript … but that [breaks if the JS fails](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html) and isn't great food for search engines.

Comment: thanks a lot ... I made some edit my question  to help understand all my points